# Problem with Semantic versioning in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to write my documentation for Greengrass V2 software using Sphinx. The problem is related to the use of semantic version specification for the modules of Greengrass and the build module of Sphinx (sphinx-build), which doesn't recognize the name of folders entirely and separate them by point.

For example, if I have a tree directory as follows:

```
-docs
-com.example
--1.0.0
---test.py
```

The build command in the terminal throws the following error:

> WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'temp.temp' from module 'com'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'com'

I tried to look up the solution on the internet, but didn't find it.

Comment: It is not clear how this is related to semantic versioning. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It is related considering the name of the folders, Sphinx can't deal with names containing points; "com.example" or "1.0.0" are not interpreted as valid folder names. When the compilation comes, only characters before the first point are taken into account.

Comment: To clarify the problem, please edit the question. Describe, in detail, the steps needed to reproduce the error message ("failed to import module 'temp.temp' from module 'com'").